# Easy code adding additional information into the dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Is there another way to add the information to the datafame, an easier way?

I have a dataframe which looks like the following:

```
             Product  Price
2023-01-03     Apple   2.00
2023-01-04     Apple   2.10
2023-01-05     Apple   1.90
2023-01-03    Banana   1.10
2023-01-04    Banana   1.15
2023-01-05    Banana   1.30
2023-01-03  Cucumber   0.50
2023-01-04  Cucumber   0.80
2023-01-05  Cucumber   0.55
```

I have two additional information:

```
Apple       Fuit
Banana      Fruit
Cucumber    Vegetable
```

and

```
Apple       UK
Banana      Columbia
Cucumber    Mexico
```

this needs to be added in an additional column as shown below in the results.

```
            Product  Price  Category   Country
2023-01-03     Apple   2.00      Fuit        UK
2023-01-04     Apple   2.10      Fuit        UK
2023-01-05     Apple   1.90      Fuit        UK
2023-01-03    Banana   1.10      Fuit  Columbia
2023-01-04    Banana   1.15      Fuit  Columbia
2023-01-05    Banana   1.30      Fuit  Columbia
2023-01-03  Cucumber   0.50  Vegtable    Mexico
2023-01-04  Cucumber   0.80  Vegtable    Mexico
2023-01-05  Cucumber   0.55  Vegtable    Mexico
```

The code lokks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'Product': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple',
                               'Banana', 'Banana', 'Banana',
                               'Cucumber', 'Cucumber', 'Cucumber'],
                   'Price': [2.0, 2.1, 1.9,
                             1.1, 1.15, 1.3,
                             0.5, 0.8, 0.55]},
    index=['2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05',
            '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05',
            '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05'],
)

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
print(df)

def category(row):
    if row['Product'] == 'Apple':
        return 'Fuit'
    elif row['Product'] == 'Banana':
        return 'Fuit'
    else:
        return 'Vegtable'

def country(row):
    if row['Product'] == 'Apple':
        return 'UK'
    elif row['Product'] == 'Banana':
        return 'Columbia'
    else:
        return 'Mexico'

df['Category'] = df.apply(lambda row: category(row), axis=1)
df['Country'] = df.apply(lambda row: country(row), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the *infos* in a nested `dict`, then make a intermediate [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) for the [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) :

```
infos = pd.DataFrame({"Category": {"Apple": "Fuit", "Banana": "Fruit", "Cucumber": "Vegetable"},
                      "Country": {"Apple": "UK", "Banana": "Columbia", "Cucumber": "Mexico"}})
​
​
df = df.merge(infos, left_on="Product", right_index=True, how="left")
​
```

Output :

```
print(df)
             Product  Price   Category   Country
2023-01-03     Apple   2.00       Fuit        UK
2023-01-04     Apple   2.10       Fuit        UK
2023-01-05     Apple   1.90       Fuit        UK
2023-01-03    Banana   1.10      Fruit  Columbia
2023-01-04    Banana   1.15      Fruit  Columbia
2023-01-05    Banana   1.30      Fruit  Columbia
2023-01-03  Cucumber   0.50  Vegetable    Mexico
2023-01-04  Cucumber   0.80  Vegetable    Mexico
2023-01-05  Cucumber   0.55  Vegetable    Mexico
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I create based on the function the dict? because there is a lot of data and I cant put them manually into a dict.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Where are those informations stored ? From where do you collect them ? I mean what you you call : _I have_ __two additional information__

Comment: Please take a look into the code. There are two dunction providing the infirmation. How cann I fill the two functions category and country into a dict and merge it?

Answer (score -1):

```
df['Category'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'Fruit' if (row['Product'] == 'Apple') or (row['Product'] == 'Banana') else 'Vegetable', axis=1)
df['Country'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'UK' if row['Product'] == 'Apple' else ('Columbia' if row['Product'] == 'Banana' else 'Mexico'), axis=1)
```

Comment: The OP posted a minimum example. Consider that actual data may contain hundreds of fruit/vegetables and countries.

Comment: Maybe `map` instead of `apply`? :)

Comment: @Timeless's solution solved the problem in the mapping way. My solution is for the situation it's not worth to list all the mappings. For example, there might be hundred more items all belonging to 'Vegetable' but only two items are in the 'Fruit' category